# Finding users in a XML-file and return in a variable - second try

Tags: xml, perl

the last time I asked for help, it did not turn out to what is was looking for. Instead it was more talked about my non-well-formed XML. Therefore let me please try again to describe my problem:

The company of my client is using a huge XML file containing test departments including users of those test departments and more. An extract of a department called "Fighters" would look as following (copied 1:1 (but with different names and numbers)):

```
<config name="department" version="1.11">
     <xad version="1459" nocheckoutver="1701">
        <!-- ... -->
        <department name="/fighters" id="123879" group="channel" case="none" use="no">
            <replication region="4334">
                <options index_name="index.html" listing="0" sum="no" allowed="no" />
                <!-- ... -->
            </replication>   
            <target prefix="http" suffix=".net" />
            <!-- ... -->
            <user name="T:106603" />
            <user name="T:123879" />
            <user name="test" />
            <user name="ele::123456" />
            <user name="company-temp" />
            <user name="companymw2" />
            <user name="bird" />
            <user name="coding11" />
            <user name="plazamedia" />
            <allow go="123456=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" />    
            <!-- ... -->
        </department>
        <department name="/dancers" id="876543" group="floor" case="yes" use="no">
            <!-- ... -->
        </department>
    <!-- ... -->    
    </xad>
</config>
```

Each test department is facing a unique id (here `123879`).

So I want to get the number of all users stored in an variable by just searching for the department-id (which is included in " "). How would the command look like *in detail*?

Note: The number of users in a department vary and the department-id is stored in a variable, let us call it `$dept`.

Many thanks in advance for a solution and your patience with me still fighting with `bash` programming. Please note: If the solution would be to run e.g. a Perl script I appreciate too in getting the related code for this.

Comment: @ikegami
1) You may wanna use XML without (...)
2) :-(
3) True, things changed.

Comment: `<user="T:106603" />` and similar constructs are not well-formed XML.

Comment: @kjhughes
Right, it should be <user="T::106603" /> instead (two colons).

Comment: Number of colons is not the problem.  `<user attr="T:106603" />` or `<user>T:106603</user>` would be well-formed, for example.

Comment: @ikegami, your edit is a substantive change to OP's "XML".  m_s, do you approve?

Comment: @kjhughes, It changed `<user="plazamedia" />` to `<user name="plazamedia" />`. It's a safe bet that he has an element named `user`. The name of its attribute(s) doesn't matter since the name of the user isn't needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I fix your data to be well-formed XML (see below), you can use a tool like `xmlstarlet` to process it

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//department[@id="123879"]/user/@name' -n file.xml 
T:106603
T:123879
test
ele::123456
company-temp
companymw2
bird
coding11
plazamedia
$ xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//department[@id="123879"]/user/@name' -n file.xml |wc -l
9
```

The XML:

```
<config name="department" version="1.11">
     <xad version="1459" nocheckoutver="1701">
        <!-- ... -->
        <department name="/fighters" id="123879" group="channel" case="none" use="no">
            <replication region="4334">
                <options index_name="index.html" listing="0" sum="no" allowed="no" />
                <!-- ... -->
            </replication>   
            <target prefix="http" suffix=".net" />
            <!-- ... -->
            <user name="T:106603" />
            <user name="T:123879" />
            <user name="test" />
            <user name="ele::123456" />
            <user name="company-temp" />
            <user name="companymw2" />
            <user name="bird" />
            <user name="coding11" />
            <user name="plazamedia" />
            <allow go="123456=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" />    
            <!-- ... -->
        </department>
        <department name="/dancers" id="876543" group="floor" case="yes" use="no">
            <!-- ... -->
        </department>
    <!-- ... -->    
    </xad>
</config>
```

`xmlstarlet` can be downloaded from http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/download.php

Comment: I would like to you use your approach here (thanks for sharing). However when running, I receive the following: Entity: line 23: parser error : attributes construct error <xsl:value-of select="//department[@id="123879"]/write/@user"/> ^ Entity: line 23: parser error : Couldn't find end of Start Tag value-of line 23 <xsl:value-of select="//department[@id="123879"]/write/@user"/> ^ 0 For the sake of completion: A typcial user is <write user="test" />, not <user name="test" />. My bad; I mistyped it.

Comment: That's from Glenn's command? If so, looks like `xmlstarlet` incorrectly interpolated into an XSL template.

Comment: @m_s, if you're writing that xslt, you can't nest double quotes inside double quotes. Try single quotes: `<xsl:value-of select="//department[@id='123879']/write/@user"/>`

Comment: It now works, but unfortunately provides the wrong result as following: T::106603 + "blank".

And when using _wc -l_ it is returning a 2.

Any idea?

Comment: No. Show your work up in your question, or in a new question. Don't forget to show the input data, what you're actually seeing, and what you expect to see.

Comment: Done now. See here in case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25252040/xmlstarlet-returning-a-wrong-result.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer XML::LibXML. It's fast and robust.

You say you want the count all users, but then you specify a department id to use. I'm not sure which one you want, so I'll provide both.

To count all users:

```
my $num_users = 0;
for my $users ($doc->findnodes("/config/xad/department/users")) {
   ++$num_users;
}
```

To count the users in the specified deptartment:

```
for my $dept ($doc->findnodes("/config/xad/department[@id='$dept_id']")) {
   my $num_users = 0;
   for my $user ($dept->findnodes("users")) {
      ++$num_users;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so far. But I believe LibXML somehow how has to be referenced in the beginning and is supposed to exist beforehand, which is not the case. Neither I can download and install it due to missing privileges.

Comment: You don't need special privileges, and all the other XML modules need install too since Perl doesn't come with any.